# Как грамотно задать степень десятки в число с плавающей запятой

Tags: математика, float, double, fortran, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Мне нужно вычислить степень 10.
Я делаю это так (FORTRAN77):

```
  Z = 10.0**9
```

Но тут происходит умножение 10 на себя 9 раз. И из-за этого появляется погрешность. Я бы хотел задать степень наиболее точно, например:

```
  Z = 1E9
```

Так число задаётся ближе нужному, но это прописывается в исходном коде, а мне к примеру нужно степень считать с клавиатуры и возвести.

Хотелось бы задавать число так:

```
  I = 9 
  Z = 1EI
```

Но это не работает.

Ну и собственно вопрос: существуют ли какие либо программные способы установки вещественным переменным значения степеней десятки(в том числе и отрицательных)?

Я бы хотел получить ответ на FORTRAN77, но мне также интересно как это делают и в других языках.

Comment: И большая получается ошибка? Разница между 10**9 и 1E9?

Comment: @Mikhailo Не то чтобы большая, но есть. На меньших степенях это не очень заметно, но уже с большими сразу видно, что погрешность накапливается.

Comment: @Mikhailo К примеру при -11 степени след результаты:
1E-11: 0.99999999600419720025E-11
10.0**(-11): 0.10000003429488923956E-10

Comment: @Mikhailo
Хоть и там и там есть погрешность, но:
В первом случае погрешность примерная 0,000000004 (погрешность в 9 знаке после запятой)
Во втором: -0,000000342‬ (погрешность в 7ом знаке)

Из всех тестов, что я делал (даже на 300 степенях) погрешность небольшая (1-2) знака. Но мне никак не даёт покоя, то что я мог бы её устранить, если бы умел явно говорить программе какой порядок у моего числа, а не делать это бесконечным возведением в степень.

Comment: Я не знаю Фортран... там не может быть так, что одно значение - 8 байт, второе - 4 байта (double и float в С?). Если вам так критично - составьте таблицу и вместо вычисления берите число из таблицы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно мой вопрос решился также как и в более высокоуровневых язык. Я записал число в строку, а после считал из него:

```
CHARACTER A*7
Z = 10.0**(-11)
WRITE (A,'(E7.1)') Z
READ (A, *) Z
```

При таком методе погрешность минимальна.

Comment: В Бейсике не было функции округления. Но была возможность округлить число при печати в файл. Была написана функция "округлить", которая так и делала: писала в файл с нужным числом разрядов и читала значение из файла обратно. Я занимался вопросом почему программа для формирования отчётов так медленно работает.

Comment: Возвести в целую степень можно точно, без использования строковых операций.